# Multi-File Batch Script loop and variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, append, filenames

I previously used a program (that I can no longer use) that would modify the variables in a batch script for me according to what folder it was currently processing (the batch file however was in another location).

Example:

```
FOLDER_A = Variable 1
FILE_A = Variable 2
FILE_B = Variable 2

FOLDER_B = Variable 1
FILE_A = Variable 2
```

The program would apply the appropriate information based on what folder it was currently processing.  This was used to rename and append a time stamp based on the folder name and file name.

Since I can no longer use the program I would like to know if there is a way to write my batch script to function in the same way.

In other words, I need a central batch script that will execute for any of about 60 folders, and apply the folder name to a variable and the file name(s) to a variable.  Then I can zip up the individual files with a file name like Folder_A-File A-TIME_STAMP_HERE.zip

I don't think I can loop through folders because my task scheduler application will be executing this as files appear in the folder. Also, it needs to be completed quickly as it moves the original file after.

Any insight, help, or direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. Ok, you need a script. Besides that, have you tried anything on your own? You know, this site is about questions and answers and there's not a single question mark in your statement. You could at least take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: A time stamp based on the folder name and the file name, how would that work? I think you could give names of the folder timestamp *or* the file timestamp, but not of the name. Next question is: which of the three time stamps do you like?

Comment: All in all: although we can do a lot of things in batch files, this task sounds more suitable for a program made by a "real" programming or scripting language, e.g. PowerShell.